# Python create list of closest points for drone path

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of points and returns a new list of points,
beginning with the first point and then at each stage, moving to the closest point that has not yet been visited.

Input list: [(2.8, 9.8), (0.3, 8.3), (4.4, 8.8), (6.8, 7.4), (4.1, 0.3), (4.5, 0.0), (7.6, 1.1), (5.0, 8.2), (7.7, 1.8), (3.4, 6.9), (4.8, 3.2), (0.7, 7.9)]

Essentially I want the function to put the start point in the input list (2.8, 9.8) as the first point in the output list. Then since the closest point to the start point (2.8, 9.8) is (4.4, 8.8), (4.4, 8.8) should appear second in the list, the closest remaining point to (4.4, 8.8) is (5.0, 8.2), so (5.0, 8.2) should appear third in the list and so on.

This should output the list: [(2.8, 9.8), (4.4, 8.8), (5.0, 8.2), (6.8, 7.4), (3.4, 6.9), (0.7, 7.9), (0.3, 8.3), (4.8, 3.2), (4.1, 0.3), (4.5, 0.0), (7.6, 1.1), (7.7, 1.8)].

Really stumped on where I'm going wrong in my code, this is what I have so far:

```
def best_path(points) :
    path = []
    closest_distance = math.sqrt((points[0][0] - points[1][0])**2 + (points[0][1] - points[1][1])**2)
    previous_point = points[0]
    x = 0
    while x < len(points) :
        for i in points :
            distance = math.sqrt((previous_point[0] - i[0])**2 + (previous_point[1] - i[1])**2)
            x+=1
            if closest_distance > distance :
                closest_point = i
                previous_point = i
                path.append(closest_point)
    return path
```

This returns: [(2.8, 9.8), (4.4, 8.8), (6.8, 7.4), (5.0, 8.2), (3.4, 6.9), (0.7, 7.9)]

Should return: [(2.8, 9.8), (4.4, 8.8), (5.0, 8.2), (6.8, 7.4), (3.4, 6.9), (0.7, 7.9), (0.3, 8.3), (4.8, 3.2), (4.1, 0.3), (4.5, 0.0), (7.6, 1.1), (7.7, 1.8)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `numpy.argmin` to get the index of the point withminimum distance once you have computed them all. You also have to remove each point from `points` once you have visited it, like this:

```
def best_path(points) :
    path = []
    prev_p = points[0]
    dist = [(prev_p[0] - p[0])**2 + (prev_p[1] - p[1])**2 for p in points]
    
    while points:
        dist = [(prev_p[0] - p[0])**2 + (prev_p[1] - p[1])**2 for p in points]
        i = np.argmin(dist)
        closest_p = points.pop(i)
        prev_p = closest_p
        path.append(closest_p)
    
    return path
```

or without using `argmin`:

```
i = dist.index(min(dist))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using numpy.argmin, is it possible to write code to do the job of numpy.argmin without needing the plug-in?

Comment: it is not a plug-in, just a library. I've edited the answer with another way to get teh index

Comment: Is it possible to replace i = dist.index(min(dist)) with an if statement and then rather than doing dist = [(prev_p[0] - p[0])**2 + (prev_p[1] - p[1])**2 for p in points] you call a for loop before it?

Comment: As always with code, there are multiple ways of doiing things.